# Including framework in java - IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, frameworks, jgap

this might be a quite easy question, but I'm really getting crazy, becausse I don't get what I want working. I try so simply include a framework in my project, but I have no idea how... I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and I'm working on a little game and I want to include [JGAP](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/) in it. I therefore downloaded the zip file and extracted it to my folder, where the rest of the project is as well, so I now have the folder structure with the bin-files, the src-files (and of course some project files). In the src-folder, i put the folder, that contains the unzipped content of JGAP. Now how am I able to include that correctly? Do I have to tell that to the IDE? Or do I have to write this in the code? `import org.jpag.*` does not seem to work.

Comment: Have you considered using a dependency management system, such as Maven?

Comment: @Magnilex I didn't so far, because I'm not very familiar to java and it's environment yet. But as JGAP will be the only framework I will use, this might also be too much effort (I don't know if it really is)....

Answer (score 2):

With IntelliJ, you can add external dependencies ( jgap.jar in your case) with following procedure:

- File -> Project Structure
- Find Libraries tab, on the left
- Find '+' green button on the top of the window
- You just have to locate you archive containing your lib (**jgap.jar**)

That's it: `import org.jpag.*` should work now :)